# promise keep working when i resolve it and change page (protractor test)

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, protractor, e2e-testing

i have a table rows and i want to click on edit button in a row with specific label(test server label), 
[image: a row that i want to click it]

this is my code :

```
public selectOnRow( textSelector:string , clickableSelector : string , value:string) {
    let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        element.all(by.css(textSelector)).each((elem, i) => {
            elem.getText().then(function (text) {
                if (text === value) {
                    resolve(i);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    promise.then(i => {
        element.all(by.css(clickableSelector)).get(i).click();

    })
}
```

and i call it like this:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
            page = new AppPage;
            page.navigateTo('/asset/server');
            page.selectOnRow('.column-label div', '.edit-action-btn', 'test server label')
            baseUrl = page.baseUrl;
        });
```

the problem is it clicks on a correct row but when page is changed still  `selectOnRow` is working and looping on rows those are not in new page!
i get this error:

> Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
>   document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ElementFinderArray filter function

This might be a good use of the filter function for [`element.all`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter). When we call the filter function, elements that return truthy with a boolean or promise to a boolean get added to the `ElementFinderArray`. The `ElementFinderArray` is also the same type of object that `element.all` will return.

### Clicking on one of the elements

When the text matches, we set a variable index when the text matches. Only set the index value if the index is empty. Next we will wait for the filter function to complete. We then click on the `clickableSelector` with the `index` value.

### Awaiting async methods

Last thing to do is return the entire promise on selectOnRow. So you can call `await selectOnRow(textSeector, clickableSelector, value);`

### Code snippet

```
public selectOnRow(textSelector:string, clickableSelector: string, value: string) {
    let index: number;
    return element.all(by.css(textSelector)).filter((elem, i) => {
      return elem.getText().then(text => {
        // test if index is not set
        // also, if the text matches, update the index
        if (!index && text === value) {
          index = i;
        }
        return text === value;
      });
    }).then(() => {
      // wait for the filter function to complete
      // at this point, the index should be set.
      return element.all(by.css(clickableSelector)).get(index).click();
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't want to find all my textSelector divs and click on first of them because it's not clickable, i want to find my first textSelector div in table with my specific value and get its index to be able to find my clickableSelector with same index and click on it.

Comment: have you tried my solution? it should do the same as your original code but uses the filter method.

Comment: yes i tried, it says the element is not clickable .

Comment: sorry i missed the part where it was an index that needed to be resolved. let me fix it.

Comment: updated! please try the above. i missed the part about the clickable selector

Comment: it worked thank u so much,i missed use then in promise.